# Eclipse and Java 3D error null graphics configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, java-3d

I am trying to set up Java 3D with eclipse, but I continue to get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Canvas3D: null GraphicsConfiguration
at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.checkForValidGraphicsConfig(Canvas3D.java:963)
at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.<init>(Canvas3D.java:1006)
at hellouniverse.LA.<init>(LA.java:54)
at hellouniverse.LA.main(LA.java:73)
```

Im not sure how to fix this or what to do.

Comment: error code formatted

Comment: Thank you, after updating my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I figured out part problem was with my code. I downloaded Hello Universe to test it, but for some reason the code was written improperly.

Comment: You can use the property "allowNullGraphicsConfig". @Stanton Your advice has been obsolete for a long time, there is no libj3dcore-ogl.so in Java3D 1.6.0, there is no need of tinkering LD_LIBRARY_PATH to make it work as Java3D >= 1.6 has no native pipeline and fully relies on JOGL. Rather follow my instructions: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I've come through it today.
Extracted from [this website](https://oligoli.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/canvas3d-null-graphicsconfiguration/):

Don’t declare the Canvas3D object with null value.

```
Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(null);
```

Instead pass the GraphicsConfiguration parameter:

```
GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(config);
```